# getResourceAsStream class vs getClass()

Tags: java, resources

I'm maintaining a piece of code and I'm not sure of a condition.

```
resourceStream = StorageEngine.class.getResourceAsStream(resourceFile);
if (resourceStream == null) {
    log.info("StorageEngine: didn't find  resource file in the classes root ");
    resourceStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourceFile);
}
```

Is there really a difference between *StorageEngine.class.getResourceAsStream* and *this.getClass().getResourceAsStream* ?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there really a difference between StorageEngine.class.getResourceAsStream and this.getClass().getResourceAsStream ?

Yes, absolutely.

- If the resource name is a relative one, it will be relative to the package containing the relevant class
- If the two classes are in different classloaders, one may be able to access a resource and the other not

Of course if `this` is an instance of `StorageEngine` (and not a subclass) then they really are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, but neither are really the right way to do this.

Long answer: different classes may be loaded by different classloaders, each of which has access to a different set of files. If `StorageClass` and `this` were loaded by different classloaders, then it's entirely possible that one call will return `null` while the other succeeds.

The best all-around approach is the following:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/absolute_path");
```

In a simple packaged application, some people consider this overkill. Where it's really useful is in a web-app, where different parts of the application may be loaded by different classloaders.

The *only* time, IMO, that you should load using an explicit class is when you're writing library code and want to ensure that you're getting *your* copy of a particular resource. That situation is extremely rare; normally a library wants to use resources packaged by the application.